# How is declaring a new variable inside a loop NOT giving errors?

Tags: java, loops, variables

I'm new to android and currently learning the basics.
the code below is meant to display a list of numbers (1-10). I want to understand why the code runs with no errors in android studio and it actually displays the list. **From what I see, we are declaring the variable *wordView* multiple times without changing the variable name.** Are we updating the same *WordView* variable each time? if so, how am I getting a list?

```
LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
    int index = 0;
    while (index < 10) {
        TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
        wordView.setText(words.get(index));
        rootView.addView(wordView);
        index ++;

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't have to do with android, this is just basic programming.

Comment: Where are you declaring `wordView` multiple times in that snippet?

Comment: the concept is of basic programming but `TextView` element is of **android sdk** so you cannot rule out the tag....then in every question you have to search only the concept and set tags accordingly @TheMCProgrammer

Comment: and also the question seeker might not have the clear concept else he wouldnt have asked the question.. @TheMCProgrammer

Comment: Fair point @SantanuSur

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a variable inside a loop makes the variable only available in the scope of that instance in the loop. Basically, each iteration of the loop, the variable gets created and goes out of scope (is "forgotten") at the end of the iterations.

Comment: Okay got it. But how is it forgotten yet still a child view of the LinearLayout? am I missing something?

Comment: @NoorEldali That is completely irrelevant. All that matters is that it is a variable and it is declared inside of a while loop. The only thing that matters is where the variable is declared, which is inside the while loop, so it is only accessibly in the while loop. I hope that made more sense :-)

Answer (score 1):

Scope matters.

In each iteration a new `Object` of `TextView` gets created and died in the same iteration as the scope ends there in the same iteration.

```
while (index < 10) {
        TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
        wordView.setText(words.get(index));
        rootView.addView(wordView);
        index ++;

    }
```

Variable `wordView` gets created and ends in the same iteration.

```
while (index < 10) {
        TextView wordView = new TextView(this); // created
        wordView.setText(words.get(index));
        rootView.addView(wordView);
        index ++;
        // died here 
    }
```

As soon as the scope end, garbage collector catches that instance as there is no reference of it anymore.

Comment: Only the variable goes out of scope. The object is very likely still referenced by `rootView`

Answer (score 1):

You can gracefully define a variable within a loop **the scope of the variable** is only till each iteration. In each iteration a **new object** of type **TextView** is created but

**Remember**

you cannot **declare a variable** within `if` statement

```
   if (index < 10) {
        TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
        wordView.setText(words.get(index)); // this will throw compile time error..

        }
```